# push a viewcontroller(C) from uitabbarcontroller,C leave a white blank on bottom,but disappear after a while

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

The UITabbarController have serveral embedded UINavigationControllers.
look at this pic

Layout Pic
[image]

When I push another ViewController,look at this pic

Problem Pic
[image]

I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: I checked "Hide Bottom Bar on Push" at storyboard.

Comment: can you use a modal segue to present the view Controller C ?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)hidesBottomBarWhenPushed{ return YES; }
```

use this code, the problem solved,don't hide by storyboard,I don't know why...

Comment: try to comment that an see the changement of your views frame in viewDidLayoutSubviews you will understand

Comment: still have white blank on bottom,and disapper after a while.

Comment: yes I didn't say it to solve the problem but to make you understand why it get solved by himself , when your app load the view , it load the view with its constraint modified by the buttonBar , but when it finally get hidden by your setting , the problem get solved you can see the update in ViewDidLayoutSubViews . What you have done is force the modification before the view get set , and the reason why there is a problem is TIMING .

Comment: e,but can you tell me how can I do to solve this problem,please,this problem puzzle me a whole day.

Comment: you did it right I just explained the reason of the problem

Comment: self.tabBarController.tabBar.translucent = NO; solved